# How can I insert a typescript property inside a javascript?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a typescript property called `this.data` using the `executescript()` method of the InAppBrowser plugin but the property returns undefined instead of `'testdata'`.

I don't know if this is applicable or not or if i am doing something wrong.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, LoadingController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  browser: any;
  data = 'testdata';

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public iab: InAppBrowser
  ) {}

        showIAB(){
                this.browser = this.iab.create('http://example.com/','_blank','location=no,toolbar=yes,zoom=no,hardwareback=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done')
                this.browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(
                  ev =>{
                    this.browser.executeScript({
                      code: `document.getElementById('username-1202').value = this.data;
                      document.getElementById('user_password-1202').value = '123456';`
                    })
                  },
                  err =>{

                  }
                )
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not injecting this.data properly into the template string, replace with `${this.data}`

```
{ code: `document.getElementById('username-1202').value = '${this.data}';
document.getElementById('user_password-1202').value = '123456';`}
```

If you do the way you are doing, the "this.data" will take the context of your new window, not the original one.